# JavaFX - Change text in tableview cell

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Currently I have a mockup program [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSuyr.png).

What I want to happen is that when a user inputs a name that is currently shown in the table and clicks the "Change" button, it will change the "Status" column text of the specified name's item/row to another text such as "Running"

I currently have the following code:

Controller.java

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TableView<TableRow> tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TableRow, String> tbc_name;
    @FXML 
    TableColumn<TableRow, String> tbc_status;

    ObservableList<TableRow> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tbc_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableRow, String>("name"));
        tbc_status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableRow, String>("status"));

        tableView.getItems().setAll(gettableRows());

        System.out.println("started");
    }

    public ObservableList<TableRow> gettableRows() {
        rows.add(new TableRow("Name1", "none"));
        rows.add(new TableRow("Name2", "none"));
        rows.add(new TableRow("Name3", "none"));

        return rows;

    }
}
```

TableRow.java

```
public class TableRow {
    private String name;
    private String status;

    public TableRow(){
        this.name = "";
        this.status = "";
    }

    public TableRow(String name_, String status_){
        name = name_;
        status = status_;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

To get a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve, in `C#` I am able to change the text of a specific cell in a listview with the following code:

```
ListViewItem lvi = listview1.FindItemWithText(username);
lvi.Subitems[3].Text = "Running...";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a model class to represent a row in the tableView, then you can use it as cellValueFactory, so refactor these rows:

```
  tbc_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableRow, String>("name"));
  tbc_status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableRow, String>("status"));
```

to:

```
 tbc_name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
 tbc_status.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().statusProperty());
```

and refactor the TableRow class to :

```
public class TableRow {

    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty status;

    public TableRow(String name, String status) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public StringProperty statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }
}
```

Then you have to extend the controller with a textField(Textfield above the change button) and a button(Change).

```
change.setOnAction(action ->{
     String text = changeTextField.getText();
     tableView.getItems().stream()
                         .filter(row -> row.getName().equals(text))
                         .findFirst()
                         .ifPresent(row -> row.setStatus("Running"));
});
```